# How can I override the Git Branch specified in Jenkins Branch Specifiers?

Tags: git, jenkins

My jenkins job tracks multiple branches and triggers builds if there are changes to any of those branches. For example I have multiple branch specifiers added to my job -

origin/release**

origin/develop

The job is working fine when there are merges to any of these branches.

In some cases I want to be able to specify/input a branch to pull the source and build from. I can add a build parameter for "BranchOverride" for user input but how can I accomplish that considering I have the branch specifiers already set?

Any ideas on implementing this?

Comment: What about to: 1. Create a BranchOverride parameter with default value is something like "none", 2. Add a new branch specifier = $BranchOverride. Let me know if this works...

Comment: I tried that the first thing, and it doesn't work. For one even when I specify None, the job triggers trying to track all the branches in the repo. Even when I manually enter a value for BranchOverride, it tries to track all branches.

Comment: Related: [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/32892211/2747593) and [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/32108380/2747593). (Unfortunately neither have answers.)

Comment: I am wondering if there is a workaround. After the SCM step, later on in the Build section, if the BranchOverride parameter is set then clone that branch using git command (execute windows batch command).

Comment: Has anyone tried specifying a regex in a string parameter as a default value with something like :(?=(origin/develop|origin/release)).* and using that as the branch specifier? And that same parameter can be used to build manually from specific branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using a workaround. I created a build parameter, called BranchOverride which has a default value, the regex 
:^(?=(origin/develop|origin/release)).*

In the branch specifiers I have ${BranchOverride}

So by default I am tracking the develop and release/* branches, and when needed a user can input a branch name and the BranchSpecifier parameter would take that value to build manually.